# GTK window does not disappear after calling destroy()

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to display a confirmation window from a Python 3 script with the following code:

```
import time
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(modal=True, buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL)
dialog.props.text = "Why won't this window dissappear?"
response = dialog.run()
dialog.destroy()
dialog.destroy()
dialog.destroy()

if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('Cancel')

time.sleep(100000)
```

I expect the window to disappear after clicking "OK" or "Cancel". However, the window remains visible until the program ends. What can I do to make the window disappear?

Note: I want to prompt the user for confirmation in an otherwise simple and linear shell script. I'm not looking to implement a full GTK application, just to ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give Gtk time (or commands) to update the destroyed window. Try this code:

```
import time
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(modal=True, buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL)
dialog.props.text = "Why won't this window dissappear?"
response = dialog.run()
dialog.destroy()
while Gtk.events_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration()

if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('Cancel')

time.sleep(1000000)
```